# Get the value of Monaco Editor after new text is appended

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

In the following demo using the Monaco Editor Playground, drag/droping the "box" appends text at the cursor position of the editor. However, I am unable to get the appended value of the Monaco instance. Doing "Monaco.getValue()" is only getting the original text content and not the updated/appended one. Can anyone who is familiar with Monaco Editor help help me to get the updated text value?

[Monaco Playground Demo](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.35.0#XQAAAALAAwAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdTxLeHhepyeply1uewY4Eqs_V-0yaEJ1UdzWFC7yLjY8rwW48ZJpa0Hdy499NeF2gY2h-y85vIlyAuYfc4eWDb70K05WHH8kTXmTkbs0me_mFV4i_2E3PUapLMsp0esUU8UxJ_bFI-BjEijumZDggnFVgLifjEt8FfZj548al9u8sri-bW4HQztnCD6CqGMEn76IfKcaIxm86--UsdWHVDMuvEbP16Et80Gy2iOPzEkk4MpqW2bbXgt97UTGB3VHLaMPNPlofG18z8TnWpSVulIoKGVhkmZbyw1emIeWafau_pExm7djmPwyqvJNm31zmPEVqd_6exLj0DZhyQ4vBlldjPU6tyBVvI6-6Vzsb4k5AgBfWx_8wdSgxiQQ8kDhwJbJoCbWPV5JrSbhCOkuSpo0Wth8FPiWZ2bGhzQJavxoI5BXc6W_CfK_DNJyt917zwbbxDvy72DMDMRc3atLAEvBH5JvEaU6qc1o_i6NRTtwm7xJl4NCnLJjxez-Sz03NA6UQGfhrkbtTpgZiPQaDaImBEdlOs0ha5ocb4umgxe1HFceh5O4ErRjx5RfKz880tpxyjutNFBjV80sUlipdyGO029FRECx-phIIw7Y2X7Wv8QMpiX9owM9_wtrUPxuRQZHtJMb5VNSmML7xg9N5IhjexzY4K017zRO1CN4sB05_W_SjUrm8WhIouRt4bSDRq5WQZ19mbgvt-enGk8DwDRnGVpqX5KmRIPZNfiz_5G--sjVvNH-4-TDOLC1RldTXc8lnk0YtxG5lHDDHBx6BNGEz7MW-sg5QHb_yFHpdg)